# JS modal dosent work with "getElementById"

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I made admin panel with **HTML CSS and JavaScript** and I made buttons to move about menus, but when I test console and player menu that doesn't work like **that not changed menu section.**

[How it looks in full-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1TXL.png)

And for test I put console log 123, but that still doesn't work. May CSS be the problem? Or may it's HTML the problem? Because in console it doesn't give me any error. Just clear Google Chrome console.

```js
const playerMenuButton = document.getElementById('playerMenuButton')
const playerMenu = document.getElementById('playerMenu')

playerMenuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(123)
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto&display=swap');


.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.buttons-container{
    height: 44px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute
}

.button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: #434343;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

.chat {
    color:#434343 ;
    background-color: #434343 ;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    outline: none;
}

.div-chat {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    bottom: 60px;
    width: 193vh;
}

.playerMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: translate(00%, -100%);
    opacity: 0;
    
}

.PlayerInfo {
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

.playerMenu input {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.playerMenu.show {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AdminPanel | By Richok</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="div-chat">
      <input class="chat" type="text"> 
    </div>      
        <div class="buttons-container">
            <button id="" class="button">Console</button>
            <button id="" class="button">chat</button>
            <button id="playerMenuButton" class="button">Player</button>
            <button id="" class="button">Cars</button>
            <button id="" class="button">Capt</button>
            <button id="" class="button">Controls</button>
            <button id="" class="button">AntiCheat</button>
            <button id="" class="button">Test</button>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div id = "playerMenu" class="playerMenu">
    <input class="chat" type="text">
    <div class="PlayerInfo">
      <h1>Name:</h1>
      <h1>Social Club:</h1>
      <h1>$</h1>
      <h1>Phone number</h1>
      <h1>Home:</h1>
      <h1>Warns:</h1>
      <h1>Fraction:</h1>
      <h1>Bussiens</h1>
      <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons-container">
      <button id="" class="button">Console</button>
      <button id="" class="button">chat</button>
      <button id="playerMenuButton" class="button">Player</button>
      <button id="" class="button">Cars</button>
      <button id="" class="button">Capt</button>
      <button id="" class="button">Controls</button>
      <button id="" class="button">AntiCheat</button>
      <button id="" class="button">Test</button>
   </div>
  
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate IDs are invalid. Please [validate your HTML](//html5.validator.nu/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the css, I added position:relative; and z-index:1; to class .button so now you can add event to them and click without problem

```js
const playerMenuButton = document.getElementById('playerMenuButton');
const playerMenu = document.getElementById('playerMenu');

playerMenuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(123)
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto&display=swap');


.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.buttons-container{
    height: 44px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute
}

.button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: #434343;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.chat {
    color:#434343 ;
    background-color: #434343 ;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    outline: none;
}

.div-chat {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    bottom: 60px;
    width: 193vh;
}

.playerMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: translate(00%, -100%);
    opacity: 0;
    
}

.PlayerInfo {
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

.playerMenu input {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.playerMenu.show {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AdminPanel | By Richok</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="div-chat">
      <input class="chat" type="text"> 
    </div>      
        <div class="buttons-container">
            <button id="" class="button">Console</button>
            <button id="" class="button">chat</button>
            <button id="playerMenuButton" class="button">Player</button>
            <button id="" class="button">Cars</button>
            <button id="" class="button">Capt</button>
            <button id="" class="button">Controls</button>
            <button id="" class="button">AntiCheat</button>
            <button id="" class="button">Test</button>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div id = "playerMenu" class="playerMenu">
    <input class="chat" type="text">
    <div class="PlayerInfo">
      <h1>Name:</h1>
      <h1>Social Club:</h1>
      <h1>$</h1>
      <h1>Phone number</h1>
      <h1>Home:</h1>
      <h1>Warns:</h1>
      <h1>Fraction:</h1>
      <h1>Bussiens</h1>
      <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons-container">
      <button id="" class="button">Console</button>
      <button id="" class="button">chat</button>
      <button id="playerMenuButton" class="button">Player</button>
      <button id="" class="button">Cars</button>
      <button id="" class="button">Capt</button>
      <button id="" class="button">Controls</button>
      <button id="" class="button">AntiCheat</button>
      <button id="" class="button">Test</button>
   </div>
  
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```